# Postman form-data, file upload to web api - successful but angular $http doesn't

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, multipartform-data

I have mvc & angular application.
I want to post image file to my web api.

my web api controller is:

```
  public class UploadController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Post()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = null;
        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        if(httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            var docfiles = new List<string>();
            foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
            {
                var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/"+postedFile.FileName);
                postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
                docfiles.Add(filePath);
            }
            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, docfiles);
        }
        else
        {
            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        return result;

    }
}
```

when im performing a request to post file via Postman i use this :

Headers = {
Authorization : bearer ... ,
enctype : multipart/form-data }

and and the body request is form-data with key value pair (string , file),
and this is successfully uploading my image.

what i try to send the image through my application (via angular $http):

```
var input = document.getElementById('uploadproductimage'); // FileList object
    UploadImageFactory(input.files[0])
```

and this is my factory code:

```
    return function (image) {
    var result = $q.defer();
    var formData = new FormData();

    if (image) {
        formData.append("uploadFile", image);
    }

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: SessionService.apiUrl + '/api/upload',
        data: formData,
        header: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + SessionService.getToken(), 'enctype': 'multipart/form-data' }
    })
    .success(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        result.resolve(response);
    })  
    .error(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        result.reject(response);
    });
    return result.promise;
}
```

and my html input:

```
                    <input type="file" id="uploadproductimage" name="uploadproductimage" class="input-xlarge">
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you used something like Fiddler to determine the difference in what Postman is sending vs what Angular is posting? Also, is your getToken request asynchronous?

Comment: angular request still got "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8". and in postman request: "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryvaPSgvkOAxWheGp5"

Comment: about 'getToken' - it isnt request its already stored in angular service.  The token is received before the client would upload any file.

Comment: Ah. You might want to add a new Content-Type to your header tags if you're uploading a file. Try replicating the same values as the Postman request to see if they succeed.

Comment: Thats what i say, i used the same requests (or i missing something).

Comment: I'm currently facing the same issue. Any progress on that? Thanks

Comment: Did you solve this me too stuck with this